# How much time does it take to execute a loop?

Tags: java

Is there any way to know how many seconds does it take a loop to execute in java?

For example:

```
for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {

//Do some difficult task goes in here

}
```

It does not have to be accurate 100%, but its just to have an idea of how long it could take. The algorithm inside is some kind of key generator that writes to a .txt file. I expect it to take even a few mins, so for my first test i want to count the seconds.

Comment: This will completely depend on the kind of machine  used. You will need to benchmark it.

Comment: Adding code to benchmark will add extra steps to your loop, making your benchmark inaccurate by design.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you can try this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endTime = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {

    //Something

    }

endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

long timeneeded =  ((startTime - endTime) /1000);
```

Comment: @Michael Parker: Try `System.nanoTime();`

Comment: Beware that this simplistic approach can give misleading answers.

Comment: Why are you assigning 0 to `endTime`?

Comment: In case he wants to use that code inside a method. You know that local variables don't get automatically initialized as global variables do. No other special reason.

Comment: I wouldn't round down to the second unless this is a very long running test.  Usually you only need to run a test for 2-5 seconds to get a fair idea what the timings is like.

Comment: Can't you just do `long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` Why bother setting to 0 and then setting it to System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: As i said there is no special reason why i did that, also there is no need at all for the variable end time, i could just do:
`timeneeded = ((startTime - System.getcurrentMillis())/1000)` but i didn't, no special reason.

Comment: Shouldn't it be:  double timeNeeded =  ((double)(endTime - startTime ) / 1000);

Answer (score 13):

You need to be very careful when writing micro-benchmarks in Java.  For instance:

- If the JIT compiler can figure out that the loop body doesn't affect the results of the code, it can optimize it away.  For instance:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
     int j = i + 1;
  }
  ```

  is likely to "run" very fast.
- Code runs a lot faster after it has been JIT compiled.
- Code can *appear* to run a lot slower *while* it is being JIT compiled.
- If the code allocates objects, then you need to take account of potential variability of measured performance due to the GC running, the initial or maximum heap size being too small and so on.

And of course, performance will depend on your hardware, your operating system, the version and patch level of your JVM, and your JVM launch options.

Comment: +1: When you have a long loop with doesn't do anything, you are actually timing how long it takes to determine that the loop doesn't do anything. ;)

Answer (score 4):

One way to time an operation is to take an average with nanoTime() You may want to adjust the number of iterations and you will get less variation with an average.  nanoTime is better than currentTimeMillis in that it is more accurate and monotonically increasing (it won't go backwards while the application is running)

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
int runs = 1000*1000;
for(int i=0;i<runs;i++) {
   // do test
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("The average time taken was %.1f ns%n", (double) time / runs);
```

Using printf allows you to format the result.  You can divide by 1000 to get micro-seconds or 1000000 for micro-seconds.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the operation inside the loop so what you should do is record the start time of the loop and end time of the loop and then calculate the difference. You will get the time the loop takes to finish. Example:-

```
long st = System.currentTimeMillis();

for(int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    // --- loop operation
}

System.out.print("time to execute loop"+
                     ((System.currentTimeMillis() - st) /1000));
```

Comment: Beware that this simplistic approach can give misleading answers.

Comment: Unless time goes backwards (which can happen when you adjust the clock) your times will all be negative.

Answer (score 0):

divide the number of iteration by 10^8 and you will get the answer in milliseconds
.

Comment: please edit your answer and provide some code to show how it should be done to clarify your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This java snippet will be very helpful to you.
It is a modified version of above answer

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis ();
    long startTime_2 = System.nanoTime ();
    long endTime = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 387420489; i++)
      {
      }

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis ();
    long endTime_2 = System.nanoTime ();

    long timeneeded = (-1) * (startTime - endTime);
    long timeneeded_2 = (-1) * (startTime_2 - endTime_2);
    System.out.println (timeneeded + " in milliseconds " + timeneeded_2+" time in nanoseconds " );
```